# send Header and Request in post method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send Header and Request in post method using `RestClient` library but getting error:

> Endpoint not found.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://xxxxxxxxxx/UIService.svc/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx");
var request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Authentication", jsonHeadEncrpt);
//  request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonReqEncrpt, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var responsed = client.Execute(request);
```

> Response :Endpoint not found. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net

Comment: Did you test this if working or not?`http://xxxxxxxxxx/UIService.svc/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxx`

Comment: Yes i test it but no luck ...tnx for your reply

Comment: REST request works with POSTMAN but in C# not working..Thanks

Comment: If it is not working then you done nothing.. the service is not up

Comment: Guys Found the solution need to add request.Resource  where need to assign the endpoint function..Now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Guys Found the solution need to add request.Resource where need to assign the endpoint function..Now it is working fine